# Flush rewrite rules after a term is edited

Tags: terms, rewrite-rules

I need to flush rewrite rules every time a term is created or edited.

I tried several ways with no success:

**First try**

```
function pec_flush_rewrite () {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'edit_term', 'pec_flush_rewrite', 10, 2 );
```

**Second try**

```
function pec_flush_rewrite () {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'edited_post_tag', 'pec_flush_rewrite', 10, 2 );
```

**Third try**

```
function pec_flush_rewrite () {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite -> flush_rules( true );
}
add_action( 'edit_term', 'pec_flush_rewrite', 10, 2 );
```

**Fourth try**

```
function pec_flush_rewrite () {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite -> flush_rules( true );
}
add_action( 'edited_post_tag', 'pec_flush_rewrite', 10, 2 );
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Rewrite rules shouldn't need to be flushed whenever a term is created. They should only need to be flushed when new rewrite rules are created, and they are not created for individual terms. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Because I'm creating a new rewrite rule every time I create a term.

Comment: Where do you add the new rules? They need to be added before you try to flush them.